# DropZone: "No URL provided" and "Dropzone already attached."

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, dropzone.js

I'm using dropzone and jquery. I have this code:

```
  <div id="my-image">
    <!-- .......... -->
  </div>
```

And

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

    $(document).ready(function() {
      var image_uploader = new Dropzone("#upload-image", {url: "/image_uploader", acceptedFiles : "image/*",
                                                          maxFiles: 1, maxFilesize: 1, autoDiscover: false});

      //.................
```

And yet I have these 2 errors:

```
//dropzone.js:712
Uncaught Error: No URL provided.
    at new Dropzone (dropzone.js:712)
    at Function.Dropzone.discover (dropzone.js:1641)
    at Dropzone._autoDiscoverFunction (dropzone.js:1923)
    at HTMLDocument.init (dropzone.js:1892)
```

And:

```
//jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2

Uncaught Error: Dropzone already attached.
  at new Dropzone (dropzone.js:699)
  at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):221)
  at l (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
  at c (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
```

Why are they occuring? How to fix them?

Answer (score 8):

For the first error you have to add `Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;`  before `$(document).ready(function (){})`

For the second error I think you are declaring Dropzopne.js twice.

Comment: P.S. The reason you need to `Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;` outside of `$(document).ready(function (){})` is because by the time the document.ready function fires, all libraries have loaded (including Dropzone), meaning it will automatically begin its search per its default configuration. By running this before the document is ready, you are overwriting that particular default of the library.